# É seguro usar requisições ajax muitas vezes e repetidamente?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Quero criar um 'mini servidor' para eu utilizar no meu site (tumblr), para uma comunicação real com meus visitantes e uma forma de fazer isso é usando requisições ajax. Quando o site carregar, ele solicita um arquivo JSON, quando eu receber esse arquivo a requisição é feita novamente e assim por diante. Quando eu atualizar o arquivo JSON, o site recebe ele quase que imediatamente, então os dados vão ser atualizados para os visitantes.

Tenho dúvidas quanto a fazer isso, não sei se pode travar o site, pegar muita internet ou ter algum efeito ruim.
Vocês acham que eu posso fazer isso ou tem algum jeito melhor?

Comment: Essa "comunicação real" da qual você comenta, seria uma espécie de chat?

Comment: Chat não, mais sim uma notificação no site, ao informativo, não exatamente um chat.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entedi, sua idéia é que tenha por exemplo uma mensagem no site, que quando você editar no seu servidor, ela em tempo real apareça pra qualquer pessoa que visitar o site, correto?

Comment: Não travaria o site, gastaria muita banda de ambos os lados (cliente e servidor), o que é ruim para quem usa banda limitada. Mas se o intervalo entre requisições for algo superior a 30 segundos, por exemplo, imagino que seja até aceitável.

Comment: Sim @Kazzkiq, mais no caso eu atualizaria um arquivo no Google Drive mesmo (rsrsrsrs).

Comment: O problema é que realizar uma requisição ajax a cada X segundos é relativa ao cliente, ou seja, se 500 pessoas entrarem no site, seriam disparadas 500 requisições simultâneas a cada X segundos, e em termos de desempenho isso é bem complicado. Seu caso parece ser típico de problemas onde a solução seria usar [Ajax polling ou Comet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet/12855533#12855533).

Comment: Ajax pooling é o que ele está falando. Comet é a junção de várias técnicas. No caso ele teria que usar Ajax pooling porque ele pretende usar o Google Drive como hospedagem. Porém isso geraria um problema já que um gasto de banda acima do normal poderia gerar problemas quanto ao limite de uso do serviço.

Comment: Eu recomendaria que ele utilizasse um serviço próprio de notificação ou, caso quisesse mais controle, usasse o [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com). Ele usa WebSockets, o que torna o tempo de resposta mínimo e sua versão gratuita suporta até 50 usuários simultâneos.

Comment: pois então, eu descobri o Firebase a alguns dias, pensei em várias vantagens de usar ele, mais fiquei desapontado ao saber que ele só suporta 50 usuários, então pensei nessa ideia de usar ajax.

Comment: *Você quer barato ou quer bom?*

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk quero os 2 u.u

Comment: Quando você falou que está usando o Tumblr e o Google Drive consideramos que você não irá pagar por hospedagem. Existem hospedagens gratuitas, limitadas e eficientes; gratuitas, não limitadas e não eficientes; e pagas de todos os tipos.

Comment: O Tumblr, o Google Drive e boa parte das boas hospedagens gratuitas são do primeiro tipo, logo mesmo se você usar um `$.ajax` carregando um arquivo algo pode dar errado. Conheço algumas hospedagens do segundo tipo, mas não recomendo. As do terceiro tipo não conheço *pois sou pobre*.

Comment: kkkkkkkk pois então, não tenho dinheiro pra ficar usando nessas coisas, então pensei em usar eles mesmo =P. Mas é uma boa ou não usar esse método? _Tem outro serviço que recomenda?_

Answer (score 4):

Tudo vai depender do tamanho padrão da sua resposta e da performance da consulta. O ideal é trafegar apenas os dados que serão consumidos. Você pode, por exemplo, passar em cada requisição o ID da última conversa que o usuário buscou, e trazer as seguintes a partir daquela.

Uma forma de fazer isso é usar uma função javascript que a cada *x* segundos recupere os dados. No entanto, é importante que novas requisições sejam feitas somente após o término das últimas - por isso não é aconselhável usar `setInterval`, já que, se a requisição demorar mais segundos para ser processada do que o intervalo de disparo de consultas, você fica com um encavalamento de requisições. Você garante isso através de recursão em uma função auto-executável não-anônima:

```
(function loop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Inteligência da requisição
        if (complete)
            loop(); // Executa novamente a função quando a requisição atual terminar. Pode ser o **complete** do jQuery.ajax, por exemplo
    }, 5000); // Função, intervalo em milissegundos
})();
```

Comment: Eu ia fazer assim mesmo, só que sem o intervalo, assim quando a requisição acabar ele já solicita uma nova. Mais vou fazer usado o setTimeout mesmo

Comment: Com o `setTimeout` você não castiga tanto seu servidor... Muitas consultas subsequentes podem disparar centenas de pedidos por segundo ao seu servidor de um único cliente, se o retorno for rápido. Não é tão problemático assim que o usuário espere 5 segundos por novas mensagens.

Comment: Apple, você sentiu [falta das chaves](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/)? *(desculpe se esse é seu estilo de código)*

Comment: Por alguns dias pensei que fosse uma crítica ao não uso de chaves. Agora entendi a relação!